# Multiple Server_name

Tags: nginx

I have an internal php application that kept freezing on users basically every afternoon. I used to restart the application(docker) and that would relieve the issue for a day but not resolve it for good. So today I took a deeper look at the nginx error log. Looking more closely at the errors made me realize that the request was sent to 172.17.8.101. This ip is a local ip that i use locally for development but when I push to production the ip is 192.168.254.96. So i thought I could put two different ips in the server block but I must be mistaken.

```
2015/03/03 15:44:44 [error] 42#0: *7006 open() "/var/www/contentlibrary/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.254.63, server: 172.17.8.101, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.254.96:8083"
2015/03/03 15:44:44 [error] 42#0: *7006 open() "/var/www/contentlibrary/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.254.63, server: 172.17.8.101, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.254.96:8083"
2015/03/03 14:11:17 [error] 40#0: *6715 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.254.80, server: 172.17.8.101, request: "POST /pagecreator/index.php/page_creator/grouping/getGroupsByContentId HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.254.96:8083", referrer: "http://192.168.254.96:8083/app/index.php?user=John%20Doe"
2015/03/03 14:22:15 [error] 40#0: *6726 open() "/var/www/contentlibrary/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.254.63, server: 172.17.8.101, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.254.96:8083"
```

The server block in the conf file was using multiple server names. Since this breaks in production how would support my development environment without creating two different server blocks?

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

index  index.php index.html index.htm;

## Content Library
server {
    server_name 172.17.8.101 192.168.254.96; // Problem HERE
    #access_log logs/contentlibrary_access.log;
    root /var/www/contentlibrary;
    #default_type text/html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
    }

    location /app{
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php /index.php$uri  =404;
        root /var/www/contentlibrary/app;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|html|htm|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|doc|xls|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|flv|txt|xml|docx|xlsx|js)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri =404;
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
    }
```

Comment: Can't see any `listen` directive in your config

Comment: Also `connection timeout` means you need to fix PHP app

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors in the php logs or the app logs so I didn't think the error was in the app but I can keep digging. Nginx listen directive defaults to listen *:80. Do I still need to put it in the server block?

Comment: Why then it logs `host: "192.168.254.96:8083"`?